# Trying to get the results from function b to use in function c, how do I do it when they're not under the same function?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to get the results from function b to use in function c, how do I get it?

```
function b()  {
  var a = 1
  some content to tell what to do with 'a'
}
function c() {
  /* trying to multiply 'c' by the result from function b */
  some content
}
```

Comment: The answer all depends on how you want it to work. There is no right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` the value in your `b` function so that you can use it in your `c` function.

```
function b() {
  var a = 1;

  return a;
}

function c() {
  return b() * 5;
}
```